# How to Filter EmbeddedDocument in mongoengine and get value of a field?

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I am working on Credits model with transactions as embedded documents. Following is th structure in which it is stored.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546dae8cc09e5f0d9602e632"),
    "user" : ObjectId("53e7fdaac09e5f12a1230c14"),
    "transaction" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-11-20T12:34:12.878Z"),
            "amount" : 100,
            "follow_num" : "d5571d91-e434-4b10-bbd8-2a6511e78011",
            "memo" : "test1",
            "trans_type" : "deposit",
            "status" : "success"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-11-20T13:03:49.851Z"),
            "amount" : 500,
            "follow_num" : "2fd57cf4-eb5d-4751-9c88-6158adda6572",
            "memo" : "test2",
            "trans_type" : "withdraw",
            "status" : "failed"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-11-20T22:54:19.892Z"),
            "amount" : 20,
            "follow_num" : "c2bd7dd2-3b17-41c2-9513-60a058a5622a",
            "memo" : "test3",
            "trans_type" : "deposit",
            "status" : "success"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to retrieve amount of the last successful deposit transaction
(i.e. transaction.trans_type="deposit" and  transaction.status = "success").

```
@property
def last_deposit(self):
    credit_obj = Credits.objects.get(user=self,
                               transaction__match={"trans_type":"deposit","status":"success"})
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you're having trouble using the fields within your embedded document for querying. You can use a double underscore to query nested fields. Also, you should use `filter()` instead of `get()`, as het is intended for queries which will only match a single document (and will actually return an error if more than one document is found).

```
  credit_obj = Credits.objects.filter(
    user=user_id,
    transaction__trans_type="deposit",
    transaction__status="success"
  ).order_by('-transaction__date').first()
```

Also, if you're using `get()` you should catch possible exceptions.

```
from mongoengine.errors import DoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned
from bson.errors import InvalidId

try:
  credit_obj = Credits.objects.get(
    user=user_id,
  )

# verify that user_id is a valid ObjectID
except InvalidId:
  print "Not a valid ObjectId: '%s'." % str(user_id)
  # code to handle error

except DoesNotExist, e:
  print "Could not get '%s'. Error: %s" % (user_id, e)
  # code to handle error

except MultipleObjectsReturned:
  print "Multiple objects matched query."
  # code to handle error
```

Answer (score 1):

Since u wanted **only the amount of the last successful deposit transaction**  this would do the job

```
import pymongo

c=pymongo.Connection(host="localhost",port=27017)

db=c["family"]

i= db.tran.aggregate([ { "$unwind":"$transaction"}, {"$match": {"$and":[{"transaction.status":"success" , "transaction.trans_type":"deposit"}]}},{"$sort":{"date":-1}},{"$limit":1}])

a=i["result"]

a=a[0]

b=a['transaction']

print b['amount']
```

What i have done :
        Connected to local mongodb **family** database with in the **trans** collections did aggregate function to get embedded document in which i found the value for key amount from the dictionary obtained from the query

Comment: Thanks, But I want using MongoEngine